# Ubuntu 14.04: How to install Unity2d?

Tags: 14.04, compiz, unity-2d

I love Unity, but would like to use Unity2d because it doesn't run compiz. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity 2D was abandoned and removed from the repositories in the 12.10 release cycle to focus all development resources on the compiz-based Unity.

In the future the current implementation of Unity (compiz-based Unity version 7.2) will be replaced by the converged desktop experience of Unity 8, which we will then still call Unity. To my knowledge this future implementation, which is based upon Qt 5.x will not require compiz.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no Unity2D on 14.04. But, you can install the [flashback session](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-classic-gnome-flashback-session).

Although it's not the same, it should accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

Comment: While this package is available in 14.04, it is only a transition package and it doesn't actually install anything or pull dependencies in.