# Unable to reinstall unity-2d on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop LTS?

Tags: unity, 14.04, lightdm, unity-2d, xrdp

It is wiered that I'm not able to reinstall unity-2d on my system.

I removed it as it was not ready to go into the 2D mode. I have XRDP install for which I need Unity-2D.

after removing the unity-2d as it was not working properly. I run below command and then rebooted system before trying to reinstall it.

```
apt-get -f purge unity-2d lightdm
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily
apt-get -f purge
apt-get -f remove
apt-get -f autoremove
apt-get -f remove
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
dpkg --configure -a
then rebooted the system using init 6
```

now I took the ssh of my system and then i reinstalled unity using below commands

```
apt-get -f install --reinstall lightdm
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~# add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu trusty main"
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~# add-apt-repository "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu trusty main"
Error: 'deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu trusty main' invalid
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~# add-apt-repository ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily
```

To install Unity 2D, type the following commands in a terminal:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

This will install all of the necessary dependencies to run Unity 2D, including a "Unity 2D" session that you'll need to login with.

Then do the following:
 * log out
 * log back in and choose the "Unity 2D" session in the drop-down menu at the bottom of the login screen
 * you will then be running Unity 2D

More info: https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpe819_z9n/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpe819_z9n/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E32DD113 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpe819_z9n/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E32DD113: public key "Launchpad PPA for unity-2d-team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

then when I ran apt-get update everything goes well except 2 things below:

1)
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found

2)

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en_IN
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~#

above errors stared coming after I imported the PPA file of unity-2d, before that it was not there, still tried to reinstall unity-2d using below commands:

```
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~# apt-get -f reinstall unity-2d
E: Command line option 'f' [from -f] is not known.
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~# apt-get -f install unity-2d
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
unity-2d is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~# restart lightdm
lightdm start/running, process 2926
root@searce-OptiPlex-380-01:~#
```

didn't see any error while installing but even after restarting the lightdm or even after rebooting the system I am not able to see the unity-2d option at the login screen nor it is working in XRDP. Also I do not see any menu or Icons when I login to the system physically or over XRDP.

can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04: How to install Unity2d?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472701/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-install-unity2d/472793)

Comment: @Xubu-Tur Hey thanks for making the question neat and clean. I have tried the link of the question you gave in the comment and it is still not working. that's the major reason I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity-2d is not supported anymore since Ubuntu 12.04
So I doubt that you can install it on 14.04.... 
You will need to install another desktop such as mate-desktop,lxqt,lxde,kde,xfce...

with Ubuntu 1604, you can use mutiny and configure the desktop to look like unity (look alike but not the same) 
Check this [post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9005)

**Update Info** :

There is a way to configure Ubuntu in order to have xRDP connecting to the Unity Desktop.  You need to install the TigerVNC package instead of standard vnc package.  Full instructions guide can be found [at this location](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9962)

Hope this help